# what is wrong with this php statement

Tags: php

I can not seem to figure out how to write the following. The statement below is being echoed in a php string and no matter what the real value of $sex is it always shows F as being the checked value??

I found the solution and posted the working code below!

```
 $string = "Sex&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' checked='<?php if($sex == \"m\"){ echo \"checked\"; }else{echo \"\"; } ?>' /> Male
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
           <input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' checked='<?php if($sex == \"f\"){ echo \"checked\"; }else{echo \"\"; } ?>' /> Female<br /><br />";
```

WORKING CODE BELOW: (note not breaking the "checked" statement and used single quotes in if statement - works?)

```
  $the_result = $the_result."Gender  :  <input type='radio' name='sex' value='m'";
  if ($sex == 'm') {
    $the_result = $the_result." checked='checked'";
  }
  $the_result = $the_result."/> Male  ";
  $the_result = $the_result."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='f'";
  if ($sex == "f") {
    $the_result = $the_result." checked='checked'";
  }

  $the_result = $the_result."/> Female ";
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the php code with backslashes?

Comment: you have \ everywhere

Comment: @Dave Nice and simple.

Comment: Well he never asked for a detailed description :)

Comment: wouldn't I have to escape "" if it is in a string ??  edited above

Comment: what happened to statement??

Comment: @CornHoleLI - you are quite correct. But you're also including `<?php` tags inside your string, and that won't work - you can just concatenate things together instead.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is just a small part of a very large string

Comment: @Jakub,  Not asking for code. was asking what was wrong with it. The code I wrote above was semi functional in that there where no errors it just wasn't reading the variable and for no apparent reason. Others who may need to use a similar script may find it useful to see a solution, which, BTW I have not yet found and starting to believe there isn't one

Comment: SOlved the problem and have posted the working code below the faulty code

Answer (score 2):

Another, perhaps easier to understand way to write this is as follows:

```
<?php
  $str = "Sex  :  <input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' checked='";
  if ($sex == "m") {
    $str = $str."checked";
  } else {
    $str = $str."'";
  }
  $str = $str."/> Male  ";
  $str = $str."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' checked='";
  if ($sex == "f") {
    $str = $str."checked";
  } else {
    $str = $str."'";
  }
  $str = $str."/> Female ";
  $str = "<br/><br/>";
  echo $str;
```

Because you have a lot of logic around what should be echoed, you should construct your whole string and then echo it rather than trying to put logic inline. This allows you to verify the string is correct and more easily *see* what you're doing.

Note that while the above is a reconstruction of your exact logic, string construction can be done any number of ways:

```
<?php
  $str = "Sex  :  ";
  if ($sex == "m") {
    $str = $str."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' checked='checked'/> Male";
    $str = $str."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' checked=''/> Female";
  } else if ($sex == "f") {
    $str = $str."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' checked=''/> Male";
    $str = $str."<input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' checked='checked'/> Female";
  } //Note if not m or f nothing is displayed
  $str = $str."<br/><br/>";
  echo $str;
```

Or:

```
<?php
  $maleChecked = "";
  $femaleChecked = "";
  if ($sex == "m") { $maleChecked = "checked"; }
  if ($sex == "f") { $femaleChecked = "checked"; }
?>
<input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' checked='<?php echo $maleChecked?>'/> Male
<input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' checked='<?php echo $femaleChecked?>'/> Female
```

Comment: wow talk about complex the easiest way to deal with it is just a ternary statement oO

Comment: The OPs basic problem is about clarity, not about using the most concise syntax. While I could introduce ternary statements here, I didn't see a reason to when I thought the OP could simply be helped by inverting the way they're building their string. Also, punctuation is your friend.

Comment: the problem doing it your way is its alot harder to follow the code (and you've missed a closing ") I had to double take it before I got it

Comment: @Dave One more thing to note, this is not 'complex'. This is 'verbose'. There is a difference. If you wish to avoid 'verbose', best to avoid PHP altogether.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford Tried that and still showing F for everyone????

Comment: @Dave caught the closing " also missed ' after checked but I got that too no errors but still same prob

Comment: What happens if you append `echo $sex;` ahead of your switching code? Are you sure you're not always passing an `f`?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford sorry, had to run out! the echo $sex echoes the proper m or f in the case I tried it was m but selected is still f

Comment: @CornHoleLI  Then your problem is not with this section of code, but whatever is setting that variable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41988/discussion-between-corn-hole-li-and-nathaniel-ford)

Comment: Answer Above  I have edited the above question and I am showing the working code in case someone else has a simular problem